# chapters[i].find('a').attrs['title'] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Guys I try to get the 'href' because I want to go inside every one of them and download all the images inside them but I get the problem when it says has no attribute attrs

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


url = 'https://readmanganato.com/manga-dr980474'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')
chapters = []
chapters_num = []
chapters = soup.find_all('a',{"class":"chapter-name text-nowrap"})


for i in range(len(chapters)):
    chapters_num.append(chapters[i])
    chapters[i].find('a').attrs['title']
    





print(chapters_num)
```

Comment: Did you make sure `chapters[i]` has any `a` tags in it?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the title in that statement. What's the purpose of it?

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: As for the error, each chapter is, essentially, the `a` tag element. So just `chapters[i].attrs['title']` will suffice to get the chapter title. You'll likely want to stick that in a variable or something though.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comments:

1. Consider switching to a `for item in list` style for loop.
2. Consider a try/except block to help with troubleshooting as web scraping is full of potholes to catch your feet.
3. For extracting the `title` attribute from each `a`/anchor tag just go straight to the attrs without the `find()`.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


url = 'https://readmanganato.com/manga-dr980474'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')
chapters = []
chapters_num = []
chapters = soup.find_all('a',{"class":"chapter-name text-nowrap"})

titles=[]
for chapter in chapters:
    
    chapters_num.append(chapter)
    try:
        titles.append(chapter.attrs['title'])
    except:
        print('failed extracting chapter:',chapter)
print(titles) 
print(chapters_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://readmanganato.com/manga-dr980474'
req_main = requests.get(url)
soup_main = BeautifulSoup(req_main.content, 'html.parser')

data = []

for chapter in soup_main.find_all('a',{"class":"chapter-name text-nowrap"}, href=True):
    req_sub = requests.get(chapter['href'])
    soup_sub = BeautifulSoup(req_sub.content, 'html.parser')
    imgs = [img['src'] for img in soup_sub.find_all('img')]
        
    data.append([chapter['title'], chapter['href'], imgs])

for title, href, imgs in data:
    print(title, href, imgs)
```

This shows an easier way to iterate over the `a` tags. The `href=True` ensures that only entries with a href tag are returned. If you have problems with `title` missing, you could also add `title=True`.

It then shows how to get your sub pages and extract a list of all the images for each page. You probably would want to add a loop to get the images rather than just get the URLs.

This would give the first two entries as:

```
Solo Leveling Chapter 180 https://readmanganato.com/manga-dr980474/chapter-180 ['https://readmanganato.com/themes/hm/images/logo-chap.png', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_180/1-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_180/2-n.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_180/3-o.jpg', 'https://readmanganato.com/themes/hm/images/gohome.png']
Solo Leveling Chapter 179.2 https://readmanganato.com/manga-dr980474/chapter-179.2 ['https://readmanganato.com/themes/hm/images/logo-chap.png', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/1-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/2-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/3-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/4-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/5-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/6-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/7-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/8-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/9-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/10-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/11-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/12-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/13-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/14-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/15-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/16-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/17-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/18-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/19-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/20-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/21-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/22-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/23-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/24-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/25-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/26-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/27-o.jpg', 'https://v7.mkklcdnv6tempv3.com/img/tab_7/02/91/17/dr980474/chapter_179_2/28-o.jpg', 'https://readmanganato.com/themes/hm/images/gohome.png']
```